# Node.js - How to replace value of external json file without saving the whole js object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

The application data is stored in json file, the json is loaded and the object is manipulated in-memory.

How to replace value of external json file without writing the whole object to file? Is it possible to synchronize js object with external json file, so that small change in the object will write only the corresponding part of the file?

Comment: Is the amount of data that large that overwriting the file is a performance issue? If so, you should seriously consider moving the data to a more appropriate storage solution (like a database). If not, why not just overwrite the file? There isn't an easy way of changing just a part of it, expecially when dealing with text-based data like JSON.

Comment: in short answer is no (: but in long: best way to achieve speed on json data files is to split all data objects to: 1 object = 1 file  <- this will help to speed-up manipulation. otherwise I would recommend to use sqlite database. https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite

Comment: Yes, the file is quite large and i was looking for a simple and portable solution.
Thank you for the suggestion, but would rather not use SQL, because i will have to adapt the json object as tables.
I split the data to smaller files so far, it's sufficient for now. 
Maybe i will try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-portable